# TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object

This error is located at:
in RCTImageView (created by TextAncestorContext)
in BaseImage (created by Home)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Home)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Home)
in Home (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Screen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
in BottomTabNavigator (created by MyTabs)
in MyTabs (created by Nav)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by Nav)
in Nav
in Unknown (created by Route(index))
in Route (created by Route(index))
in LocationProvider (created by Route(index))
in Route(index) (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator
in Unknown (created by Layout)
in Layout
in Unknown (created by Route())
in Route (created by Route())
in LocationProvider (created by Route())
in Route() (created by RootRoute)
in RootRoute (created by ContextNavigator)
in InitialRootStateProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by NavigationContainer)
in NavigationContainer (created by ContextNavigator)
in RootRouteNodeProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandler)
in GestureHandler (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
in ErrorOverlay
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

i don't know why is happen, i just use react native expo. if i open in website nothing problem, but if i open in expo android error. please help me

TypeError:cyclicalstructureinJSONobject

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's required to post a [mcve] when asking a question - without seeing your code, the stack trace doesn't help very much. You can see [ask] for reference.